# Overwriting id of element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span element created by a JS function and want to change it's `id` when clicked. I'm trying this:
`card.setAttribute("onclick","startTurn();this.id='#a1c'");`

I want it so that when the span is clicked a function is executed and the `id` should be set to `#a1c`, and the span's previous `id` is overwritten. When I click on the span, it seems to lose it's previous `id`, but not get the new one. Any reason why?

Comment: Remove the hashtag

Comment: Oh, well that was a dumb mistake. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the hashtag from the id worked. Syntax error.